# Onclick toggle class of individual list items icon Angular 4 5 Todo application

Tags: javascript, angular, toggle, ngfor

I am battling with this and tried to find solution but failed.

I have this piece of code that list all items from input and I need for check icon to be toggled on and off on click. For now its toggle ALL icons and not individual.

```
 <p *ngFor="let task of tasks; let i = index" class=tasks @fade>
 <span class="task">
 <fa name="check" (click)="status=!status"  
[ngClass]="status ? 'check' : 'uncheck'"></fa>
{{task}}</span>
<button class="remove" (click)="removeItem(i)"><fa name="trash" 
class="delete"></fa></button>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.check{
   color: rgb(81, 255, 0);
   cursor: pointer;
}
.uncheck{
   color: red;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.
Have a great day

UPDATE:

For someone who have similar problem I found workaround. Just place input tag in your list item and style it how you wish. It will work independently for each item.

Comment: use ngModel within the *ngFor for each checkbox

Comment: It looks like you are sharing the 'status' variable between each task of tasks - I would probably just use an array of statuses so you are only dealing with status[i] within the *ngFor. You could also include a 'status' parameter to each task in tasks

Answer (score 0):

You could add the `status` properties in the `task` Object and it'd result in something like this:

```
<p *ngFor="let task of tasks; let i = index" class=tasks @fade>
    <span class="task">
        <fa name="check" (click)="task.status=!task.status"  
          [ngClass]="task.status ? 'check' : 'uncheck'"></fa>
        {{task}}
    </span>
    <button class="remove" (click)="removeItem(i)"><fa name="trash" 
      class="delete"></fa></button>
</p>
```

Comment: Hi . Thanks for answer. I get it now but cant add status to task. Do you mean in here>>>export class TasksComponent implements OnInit {
  task: string = "";
  tasks = [];
  itemCounter: number;  and how to write it

Comment: Yes, just transform your task from a string to an object: 
task: { value: string; status: boolean; }

Comment: Thanks but now its makes me a problem in other function that store items on local storage. I found workaround with input tags.